# Using PDQ to Automate PowerShell or CMD to find and delete registry entries

Tags: powershell, cmd, automation, registry

We recently started using PDQ inventory and Deploy. We have some user endpoints that have corrupted agents from a different program. The fix for this corruption includes finding and deleting a registry key pertaining to that file. I am able to use both CMD and PowerShell in PDQ as steps to automate this process. I'm kind of at a loss since the registry value is different per asset.

How can I automate the function of finding the registry key and then deleting the registry key it finds?

So far I've tied the following command to a variable:

```
$RegKey = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath } |
  Where-Object { $_ -like "*Rapid7 Insight Agent*" } |
  Select-Object PSPath
```

Similarly, in CMD the manual commands are:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\ /f "Rapid7 Insight Agent" /s
Reg Delete (with the value the previous reg query posts back)
```

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly your problem is? Also, maybe give an example of the result(s) you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Every [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-5.1) that supports the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, also supports the `Remove-Item` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products" -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -like "*Rapid7 Insight Agent*" } |
  Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this.